# How to upgrade virtual environment from previous Python version?

Tags: python-venv

I upgraded Python on my system from Python 3.5 to 3.6, and now all my virtualenvs created in Python 3.5 are no longer usable. How can I get a list of packages installed in a Python 3.5 virtualenv when I have only Python 3.6 installed? I need to setup a new Python 3.6 virtualenv with the same packages as in the old Python 3.5 virtualenv.

I know that I can look inside the `lib/python3.5/site-packages` directory and make the list manually, but I would prefer an automatic way of running e.g. `pip freeze` against the old virtual environment. I would prefer not to re-install the old version of Python.

I have tried the `python -m venv --upgrade` command, which has the help text "Upgrade the environment directory to use this version of Python, assuming Python has been upgraded in-place.". However, this doesn't actually reinstall the packages in the virtualenv, it just creates an essentially empty directory named `lib/python3.6/site-packages`. Furthermore, I had to remove the broken symlink `bin/python3.5` in the venv in order to even run `python -m venv --upgrade` against the old virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pkg_resources.find_on_path()`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/aec3649c91a2a55e218edd038571931704a8e3a6/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L2003) to find packages using the same logic as `pip freeze`. This works even when the virtualenv is for an older version of Python:

```
rav@novascotia:~/venvs$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 27 2017, 00:27:06) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20170306] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> entries = pkg_resources.find_on_path(None, './st-courses-3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
>>> print('pip install \\\n%s' % ' \\\n'.join('%s==%s' % (o.project_name, o.version) for o in entries))
pip install \
websockets==3.2 \
webencodings==0.5 \
wcwidth==0.1.7 \
...
```

This is the trail of code that leads from `pip freeze` to `find_on_path`:

- [pip freeze accesses get_installed_distributions()](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/d497d8a7c3047e5a4151f946d74fd5b1c206b263/pip/operations/freeze.py#L47)
- [... which accesses pkg_resources.working_set](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/d497d8a7c3047e5a4151f946d74fd5b1c206b263/pip/utils/__init__.py#L375)
- [... which invokes working_set.add_entry() on each entry of sys.path](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/aec3649c91a2a55e218edd038571931704a8e3a6/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L3069)
- [... which invokes find_distributions() on each entry](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/aec3649c91a2a55e218edd038571931704a8e3a6/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L694)
- [... which calls _find_adapter](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/aec3649c91a2a55e218edd038571931704a8e3a6/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L1936)
- [... which results in find_on_path](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/aec3649c91a2a55e218edd038571931704a8e3a6/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L2003)

Answer (score 1):

It seems easy to get a virtualenv into a situation where it will not upgrade. You can probably fix the venv manually, but I think it is easiest to start again.

In brief:

- Create a new virtualenv
- Copy into it the directories in your old venv that are not part of the venv environment.
- In the old environment: `ls -1 lib/python3.5/site-packages > requirements.txt`, then clean it up by hand
- In the new environment `pip install -r requirements.txt`

See this related question:
[Update a Python virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808361/update-a-python-virtualenv)